# SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400

Tags: solr

I'm trying to post some document(json format) into solr using the below commands in command prompt, but always I'm getting 400 Bad Request error.
Java_Version:1.8.0; Solr_Version:7.2

CMD:

```
C:\..\..\solr-7.2.1\example\exampledocs>java -Dtype=text/json -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update -jar post.jar books.json
```

Error:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"This IndexSchema is not mutable.",
    "code":400}}
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.062
```

I've added the request handler in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
```

and  `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` -> for referring to schema.xml file

Schema.xml: (new fields added for my indexing)

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>  

<!-- new fields -starts -->
<field name="cat" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="price" type="pdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<!-- new fields -ends -->
```

My Unique key is 'ID'.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use java -Dc=core_name -Dauto=yes -Dtype=application/json -jar post.jar *.json

i dont know why it worked.

Comment: `-Dtype=application/json`  was what was missing for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you started with the schemaless configuration, there is going to be an update chain defined for any update request. You'll have to remove [that configuration to stop Solr from trying to automagically create fields](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schemaless-mode.html#SchemalessMode-DefineanUpdateRequestProcessorChain) for you (which won't work when you're using the old style `schema.xml`).

This is defined in the `solrconfig.xml` file, and should be removed:

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="update.chain">add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

You shouldn't have to remove the chain itself, just the initParams for the update paths.

Comment: Again same issue. 400bad request.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct file? Did you reload the collection/core?

Comment: I've included the file